# Execute python script by button from android studio

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, serial-port, iot, android-studio-3.0

I am building an IoT application and I want to run my python script in the backend when I press the button in the android studio.

> **Note: The python script will just connect to the database and send it to arduino serial monitor.**

*Any Ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Chaquopy – Python SDK for Android**
https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/